# Как отключить постоянное мигание синего светодиода во время работы Repka Pi3?

Tags: ubuntu

Я так понимаю, что это говорит об активности CPU. Во время загрузки ладно, а во время штатной работы нужно отключить.

- Repka Pi3 1.2 GHz.
- Версия прошивки: Repka-OS-09.08.23.
- Вариант распиновки: 1.
- Система Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS aarch64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Андрею из Телеграмм-канала Репки. Чтобы выключить:

`echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/rbs\:red\:status/brightness`

Если нужно, выключение после перезагрузки, в папке /storage/.config нужно создать файл с содержимым:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/rbs\:red\:status/brightness
```